# Is it possible to share a variable(global) between two or more Vbscripts?

Tags: variables, vbscript

Is it possible to share a variable(global) between two or more Vbscripts ?

Example - There are two .vbs programs. 
"One.vbs" -
Public a
a = InputBox("Enter your name") 
MsgBox ("You entered: " & a)

"two.vbs" - 
MsgBox a

Is it possible that the "two.vbs" will provide the same output(after the one.vbs is executed) ?

Comment: The answer can be both Yes or No. It depends on what you are doing and what is the exact meaning of "two vbscripts". As is, the question can no be answered. Include aditional information on what you are trying to solve, how, and what are the problems you are finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, the easiest way would be to use a text file to transfer the info:

A.VBS

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("28341578.txt").Write InputBox("Your name, please!")
```

B.VBS

```
WScript.Echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("28341578.txt").ReadAll()
```

Alternatives: Environment variable, registry entry, other file types (Excel, SQLite, ...), a 'real' database.

Comment: Are there any alternatives that don't require writing to the drives? (Ssd's life span is shortened by multiple writes) other than running two.vbs with an argument.